# Removing items from an angularjs ui dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to dynamically remove elements from a angular-ui dropdown instance, but the dropdown contents seems to 'reset' to the element I want to remove.

Here's a plunker illustrating the problem, you can either click on 'external remove' or on one of the dropdown elements to trigger the phenomena.

http://plnkr.co/edit/y4myttDQBDUymJYQEfmL?p=preview

Code used to remove:

```
$scope.remove = function(index)
{
    $scope.items = $scope.items.splice(index,1);
};
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You can use splice in place as a function. Try `$scope.items.splice(index, 1);` without the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'splice' function returns the item that is removed. Just use.

```
        $scope.items.splice(index,1);
```

And don't set items to the return value.